# Communicate between two local Mac machines when one is on VPN?

Tags: network, wifi, vpn

I'd like to directly connect (be able to use ping/ssh or other common commands) two local Mac machines as one sometimes is on VPN. The two Mac normally are connected via a wireless router when none of them are on VPN. The VPN does not allow split tunnel. Once a Mac is on VPN, it can not access the other Mac behind the router.

The only solution I can think of is to directly connect them without using the wireless router. I'd prefer not to use a wired connection. However, it seems that this can not be done wirelessly, as via wireless a Mac can either connect to the wireless router or connect to a local network set up by the other Mac but not both.

Could anybody let me know a good way to solve this connection problem when one local Mac is on VPN? Thanks.

Comment: You can either connect the Macs directly (Mac to Mac) *or* via a router (Mac to Router to Mac), so right now your question is kind of asking the impossible. But in case both Macs are already connected to the same router: is your question more about how you can access one from the other within a home network?

Comment: One is on VPN, therefore, it can not access the local network. So I have to find an alternative way to connect both Macs directly.

Comment: What kind of VPN are you using? Is this something you installed on your own or is it mandated by your company/school/whatever?

Answer (score 1):

Click on wireless icon, then Create network, edit name and confirm.
From 2nd machine connect to this wireless network.

Comment: But I can only choose either this connection or the normal connection to my local router. I'd like to connect to both this computer and the local network from the router. Is it possible? Thanks.